# Next js image in public folder not found

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying to use images exactly like stated in the [Nextjs documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image), that is to say:

- Images are stored in src/public
- I use the path `/my-image.jpg` in my page.

The public directory is the one created by Create Next App, and here is how I am trying to use it in `src/pages/posts/index.js`:

```
import React from "react";

import Head from "next/head";
import Image from 'next/image'


const articlesList = [
  {title: "Article 1", classes: 'grid-element--triple-width grid-element--double-height'}, 
  {title: "Article 2"}, 
  {title: "Article 3", }, 
  {title: "Article 4", classes: 'grid-element--double-height'}, 
  {title: "Article 5"}, 
  {title: "Article 6"}, 
  {title: "Article 7"}, 
  {title: "Article 8"}, 
  {title: "Article 9"}, 
  {title: "Article 10"}, 
  {title: "Article 11", classes: 'grid-element--double-width grid-element--double-height'}, 
]

export default function Blog() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Blog</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
      </Head>
      <div className="blog-grid">
        {articlesList.map(article => {
          const {title, classes} = article
          return (<a href="/posts/first" className={`grid-element ${classes}`} key={title} >
          <Image src="/IMG_1419.jpg" width={500} height={300} alt="…"/>
          </a>)
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

However, I get 404 error when running the project locally. Do I need any extra configuration? I don't see it mentioned in the documentation for this case. I tried rebuilding but still nothing.

By the way, the same happens by using Next's Image component, as well html `img` tag.
I am using next version 10.0.2.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone else runs into this issue, the problem was that for some reason my project was created inside `src` folder. Next expected it to be at the very base directory of the project, right next to node_modules, etc.

Answer (score 1):

****It would helped if you've shown the code.

If you are using the image other than from the src/public or local folder you have to specify the source of image in next.config.js file.

Also 404 error is for not found that means if you've done everything right then Next.js is finding some difficulty in locating your images.

Tip*

1. Try Checking the image name properly.
2. Try Restarting the server.

Comment: I am trying to use the image from `src/pages/posts/index.js`.
I rebuilt and restarted the application several times but to no avail.

Comment: Calling location doesn't matter. Can you be able to show me the code

Comment: I just edited the post with the file where I try to use the image.

Comment: ```img``` tag is self closing
also width and height is not acceptable like this in img tag try giving it in old conventional method

Comment: That was remnant from next's `Image` component. I reset it there.

Comment: Why you are using ```<a></a>``` tag here first of all use ```<Link></Link>``` from ```next/link``` also try refactoring your code you may not need a ```return``` stmt here.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the images in /public were abcd.PNG

Case matters on vercel. In short, PNG !== png

Now, on localhost, src='abcd.png' works fine on local but not on vercel. But for some reasons changing it to exact cases that is to src='abcd.PNG' worked fine on build and even on vercel.

Old Image tag

```
 <Image src="/success.png" alt="some-image" width={800} height={400} />
```

realised, /public had all images with extension of "something.PNG". so changed to

```
 <Image src="/success.PNG" alt="some-image" width={800} height={400} />
```

Answer (score 1):

In case if someone else faced this issue when images not showing in `Vercel production build`, well, Vercel accepts `.svg` images, and the path simply should be starting from the base Url (`/`), static files, like images, should be under a folder called public in your root directory, and files inside public can then be referenced in your code starting from the base URL (`/`)

e.g `<img src="/imgs/logo.svg" alt="My Logo" />`

This was my issue and fixed it with this solution, hope it helps you as well